# why is the loop infinite?

Tags: c++, file, io, stdin, eof

```
char s;
list<char> inp;

while(s=fgetc(stdin),s!=EOF)
{
    inp.push_back(s);
    printf("%c",s);
}
for(list<char>::iterator n=inp.begin();n!=inp.end();n++)
{
    cout<<*n;
}
```

The while loop in the above code is never being terminated ? This may happen if EOF is never recieved from stdin. How can this happen?

Comment: Why is there a comma in while condition? Did you put that intentionally? I think there should be a logical operator there.

Comment: No I've put that code (before) intentionally to be executed whenever a iteration of the loop occurs

Comment: What is your `stdin`? Did you divert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `s` an `int`. The [`fgetc()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/) returns an `int`, since `EOF` is defined as one.

```
int s;
```

Change it to:

```
while((s=fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
{
    inp.push_back(s);
    printf("%c",s);
}
```

Also, `EOF` is not read automatically when using `stdin` unless you are using a pipe.

Think about it this way...

The program waits for the user to type in characters. How would the program know if `EOF` has been reached or the user is thinking about what to type next. The user has to send `EOF` to the program by typing `ctrl+D`.

The exception is when you have redirected `stdin` to a pipe. For example, if you compiled your program to `a.out`:

```
cat "myfile" | a.out
```

Comment: Still the loop is not terminating

Comment: _"Why should I change it?"_ Although solutions are helpful on SO, explanations are better (because this answer can not only help the original poster but others who stray here from Google or other search engines).

Comment: @Geoff_Montee What I think about stdin is that it is a simple struct holding a pointer to the buffer region. Do you want to say that this buffer does not have EOF unless ctrl-D is pressed?

Comment: Got the thing. BTW can you give me some some reference about piping.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee one thing more. Why you suggested to change the variable s to int from char?

Comment: Because `char` can only represent 256 values (-128..+127, or 0..255) and `EOF` does not have one of these values.